# Why do so many people remember Dolly from Moonraker having braces?

Tags: james-bond, moonraker

Near the end of the James Bond movie Moonraker (1979), there is a scene in which Jaws (the big bad guy with metal teeth) gets trapped under some ruble after a fight with Bond. A cute blond girl with pigtails comes over and helps him out. He smiles, with his metal teeth reflecting the sunlight, and Dolly (as many people remember it) smiles back with braces on. They then walk off together without saying a word, holding hands. The joke of course is that they are both metal-mouths.

If you go back and watch the film now, Dolly no longer has braces! It's not just the VHS or DVD or director's cut, but rather there are no copies in which she ever had braces to be found anywhere. Many people refer to this as a "Mandela Effect" (I won't explain it here but you can easily look it up.)

Is there a more mundane explanation?

There's even a [Sampo Visa Mini card commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BhLAWP7jGA) with Richard Kiel (who played Jaws) that came out over 10 years ago, in which the checkout girl smiles back at him with braces on - a clear reference to the movie.

Comment: I'm kinda unsure about this question.  to me, it reads more of a psychology question

Comment: I'm curious about what evidence there is to suggest "so many people" remember this particular detail.  How many people is "so many" and how were their answers recorded?  (ie: if ten people are sitting around in a circle and two of them say they remember Dolly having braces, the odds begin to skew towards the other eight saying they remember braces, too)

Comment: but..but.. I remember braces too - surely that was the whole thing about them being a potential 'match'.

Comment: Somebody went to the effort of doing a frame by frame analysis & comes to the same conclusions - http://dolly.barriereader.co.uk/dolly.html

Comment: Another example: http://www.newstatesman.com/science-tech/internet/2016/12/movie-doesn-t-exist-and-redditors-who-think-it-does

Comment: Maybe it's just subconscious suggestion.  Jaws meets a pretty girl and they get along famously right off the bat - **for no reason that the movie ever bothers to explain**.  Since Jaws is an antagonist, people are subconsciously less willing to accept the simple fact that a pretty girl likes him without being given a specific reason why, so their minds fill in the most obvious reason - she must've had braces - and alter their memories of the film accordingly.  A few people jump to this conclusion and begin spreading it around and voila - everyone remembers what makes sense.